# Moving to one section from another section in React, MUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a navbar on my page header with a few buttons/navigation, which is the same number of sections on the page(each section is an individual component). What I want is, to move to a particular section when I click the regarding nav button. In plain HTML I can do this using href to the section id. Is there any stander way of doing this in `material UI? if yes, how to do that.